# Print file paths from a list in python using exec in a tkinter label

Tags: python, list, tkinter, executable

I want to display a list of file names in a tkinter window. the list consists of file paths.

I've successfully used the code below with a list of string items. I'm wondering if the fact that my list `file_list` is my problem because its file paths. Maybe file paths show up differently in my list so i need to handle differently?

```
for y in range(len(file_list)):
    exec(f'Label%d=Label(InfoWindow,text="%s")\nLabel%d.grid(row={y}, 
    column=0, sticky=W)'%(y,file_list[y],y))
    InfoWindow.mainloop()
```

I am expecting a file path from the list to show up in a each row of my window but it's not. instead i get this error message:

```
exec(f'Label%d=Label(InfoWindow,text="%s")\nLabel%d.grid(row={y}, column=0, sticky=W)'%(y,file_list[y],y))
  File "<string>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 12-13: malformed \N character escape
```

Comment: instead of using variable `Label1` better keep it on list or dictionary `all_labels[1] = Label(...)`, `all_labels.append( Label(...) )` and then you don't need `exec`

Comment: You should not be using `exec` like this - there are much better ways to store references to widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create `labels` for you in the window, also the `dict` can be used later for references.

```py
name_dict = {}
for i in range(len(file_list)):
    name_dict[i] = tk.Label(InfoWindow,text=file_list[i]).grid(row=i,column=0, sticky='w')
```

Comment: copied that right in and it worked! this looks much easier to digest too. Thank you!!